param works as expected with 64-bit but not with 32-bit PowerShell
When the below runs with a 64-bit Powershell on a 64-bit Windows, The listing of the directory that is passed as an argument in commandline while running the powershell script, happens correctly.
param (
    [string]$Path = "."
)

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path 


But when I force it to run as a 32-bit Powershell on a 64-bit Windows, it gives an error saying param is not recognized as cmdlet as shown below, and the listing of current directory . happens, not the directory passed as argument. It is also the same behaviour if I keep param at the very beginning as well.
# Check if the script is running in 64-bit PowerShell
if ([Environment]::Is64BitProcess) {
    # Path to the 32-bit PowerShell executable
    $powershell32 = "$env:windir\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"

    # Relaunch the script in 32-bit PowerShell
    & $powershell32 -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File $PSCommandPath
    exit
} else {
    # Running in 32-bit PowerShell, continue executing the script
    Write-Host "Script is running in 32-bit PowerShell."
}

param (
    [string]$Path = "."
)

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path 


Error:

Any idea why this would happen and how to resolve it?

The second snippet is just wrong, the param block has to be at the top of your script.


The error message isn't very helpful, but your problem is that param() declarations must be the first statement in a script or function in order to be recognized as such; the only exceptions are that it may be preceded by comments[1] or using statements.
When placed later in a script or function, param is surprisingly treated like a command name, which triggers the error that you saw.
Therefore:
# The param(..) block must come FIRST.
param (
    [string]$Path = "."
)

# Check if the script is running in 64-bit PowerShell
if ([Environment]::Is64BitProcess) {
    # Path to the 32-bit PowerShell executable
    $powershell32 = "$env:windir\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"

    # Relaunch the script in 32-bit PowerShell
    & $powershell32 -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File $PSCommandPath $Path
    exit $LASTEXITCODE
} else {
    # Running in 32-bit PowerShell, continue executing the script
    Write-Host "Script is running in 32-bit PowerShell."
}

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path 

Note:

$Path is appended to the & $powershell32 ... call in order to pass the original $Path argument through.

Also, for general robustness, exit was replaced with exit $LASTEXITCODE, so as to pass the process exit code through as well.



[1] There is no dedicated help topic describing the comment syntax, though it is discussed in the context of about_Comment_Based_Help. The short of it is: # starts a single-line (to-the-end-of-the-line) comment; <# ... #> forms potentially multiline comment blocks that may also be used intra-line; nesting them is not supported, however.
